# How is a force distributed in a lever pushing against multiple objects?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am trying to calculte the minimum required strengths of a few parts in a construction a scouting group is building. However I cannot find details about how a levers force is distrubuted. Propose the following situation:

[image: construction]
Line d represents a 16 meter long beam that is hanging over to the left by a total of 2 meters. Because d is not straight up it generates a torque.
My question is: how is this torque distributed between beams a, b and c? Heights, weights and angles can be measured for this example, but I am mainly interrested in the method.

Does the center of gravity of d effect this? I assume d's center of gravity is at about 40% of it's height.

As a futher question: (how) does this change when the angle a beam, for example b is connected to d in a 45 degree angle instead of like 80 degrees?

I assume all beams are inflexible for this situation and there is no motion. I also assume that a, b and c are connected to a immovable object of infinite strength on the left side of the construction, to simplify this a little bit.

I am not sure if this matters, but in practice the connections from a, b and c to d will be able to rotate a small amount (let's say 5 degrees) in all directions.

I discussed this with a few different people and we all had different hypothosis, to name a few:

1. Maybe a gets a greater force applied, since the lever is smallest there.
2. Maybe c gets a greater force applied, since the lever is largest there.
3. Maybe it starts rotating around the connection from b to d, making c being pushed while a is being pulled.
4. Maybe the force is equally distributed.

Now this might be a bit of a different question, this construction is build using wood which is an anisotropic material. Does the force applied by d have any impact on the maximum allowed force perpendicular to any of the beams a, b or c?

I am sorry for my English and probably wrong use of terminoligy, English is not my native language and I find translating terminoligy quite hard.

Comment: What is the function of beam d? Is it subject to any other forces?  The distribution of weight between a,b,and c will depend on how much they can flex.  What "lever force" are you concerned about?

Comment: The weight of d itself and also wind. It is also safe to assume that a,b and c can all flex equally.

Comment: @erik321123, where is the center of rotation of beam d? Also, the center of gravity of beam d should be right in the middle assuming it has a constant width and is made of one material.

Comment: D in reality gets thinner about 0.7-1.0cm every meter in length starting with about 24cm diameter. It is fine for me to just assume a flat 16cm diameter, making the center of gravity in the middle. It is rotating around its contact point with the ground. Imaging it tumbling over if he's a, b and c where not present